# How do I use git filter-branch to remove a file from my repo? ("you need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree")

Tags: git

According to the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), I can remove a file from my repo history like so:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf filename' HEAD
```

I tried this, and got this error:

```
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

So, I tried this, and got the same error:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -f  /dist/bikeMap.html' HEAD
```

After checking multiple stackoverflow questions, I also tried

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -f  /dist/bikeMap.html' master..HEAD
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f  /dist/bikeMap.html' --all
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f  /dist/bikeMap.html' --  --all
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f  /dist/bikeMap.html' master
```

Etc. All give the same error.

`git status` says

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

My git version is `2.11.0`.

EDIT: I have now also tried:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch dist/bikeMap.html" HEAD
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch dist/bikeMap.html" -- HEAD
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force "dist/bikeMap.html"' --prune-empty -- HEAD
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force dist/bikeMap.html' --prune-empty -- HEAD
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force dist/bikeMap.html' --prune-empty -- master
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force dist/bikeMap.html' --prune-empty master
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force /dist/bikeMap.html' --prune-empty master
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force /dist/bikeMap.html' --prune-empty HEAD
```

Same error.

EDIT: Progress!

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force dist/bikeMap.html' --prune-empty
```

resulted in error

```
Rewrite 419e8702fd8a5fe9ddad59a0fd7ff008edffdeab (1/47) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
fatal: pathspec 'dist/bikeMap.html' did not match any files
index filter failed: git rm --cached --quiet --force dist/bikeMap.html
```

if I `ls dist/bikeMap.html` I get

```
dist/bikeMap.html
```

So, it exists.

**How can I use `git filter-branch` to remove a file from our repo?**

Comment: Are you running it in a bare repository?

Comment: Also, maybe consider `--ignore-unmatch` in case your file isn't present in *every* commit.

Comment: @VonC what does "bare" mean in this context?

Comment: @CalebJay a repo without files, working tree, and only the .git content.

Comment: Er, well, it certainly has files.

Answer (score 3):

To use `--tree-filter`, change your `rm` command from using `/dist/bikeMap.html` to using `dist/bikeMap.html`, i.e., drop the leading slash.

To use `--index-filter`, change your command to `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch dist/bikeMap.html`, i.e., use `git rm` with extra options (and drop the leading slash).

(The index filter will be much faster.  If you just want to remove one named file from all commits that have that one named file, use the index filter with `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch`.)

Comment: Correct. In this case one should use `--index-filter` because it's faster. The following command should work : `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --quiet --force "filename"' --prune-empty -- HEAD`.

Comment: Huh, I must be not understanding how git filter-branch works at all, this still isn't working. I've added all my attempts to the question under "EDIT"

Comment: Keep the `--`, and after it list all the branch and tag names you want filter-branch to deal with, or `--all`. Using `HEAD` means "the current branch name (only)". Use `--prune-empty` at will; use `-f` if you have not cleaned up after a previous filter-branch. Add `--tag-name-filter cat` if you have annotated tags that must also be changed point to the new copies. And, last, remember that filter-branch *copies* commits: it will roughly double the size of your repository, because all the *original* commits, that have the file, are still there. They [continued]

Comment: They merely become *unreferenced* (unused) once all reference names (branches, tags, remote-tracking names, and the like) no longer refer to the original commits. Eventually—or immediately upon cloning the filtered repository—the unreferenced commits are truly discarded. Only then is the file *really* gone.

Comment: The error is due to omitting `--ignore-unmatch`. `git rm` will error out (despite `--force`) if there is no file to remove in the commit it's copying, unless you set the `--ignore-unmatch` flag (and the `-f` flag is then pointless here, though not wrong).